# Probability Question with 2 rolls

Tags: probability, dice

I have a probability question.

Say that there is a 2% chance of something occuring and then a 1d5 (20%) of it being a critical success.

So technically its a 0.4% chance of a critical success.

If we have more rolls, say 100 rolls. Would it still be a 0.4% for a critical success or would you have a higher chance?

Comment: If you want to calculate the probability of at least one success, then subtract the probability that none of the rolls result in a success from $1$.  You will find that the probability is greater than $0.4\%$ since there are more opportunities for a success to occur.

Comment: If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=100, p=.004),$ then $P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X=0).$ In R statistical software the statement `1 - dbinom(0, 100, .004)` returns 0..3302174

Answer (score 0):

For independent rolls, the chance of *no* critical success is the chance of not getting critical success on one roll, times $100$:

$P_0 = (1 - 0.004)^{100}=0.996^{100} \doteq 0.6698.$

Then, the probability of getting critical success on *at least* one roll of a hundred is

$P_{>0} = 1 - 0.996^{100} \doteq 0.3302,$

or about $1/3$.